# How to approach and design a qualitative data color scheme for over 20+ layers on a map?

Tags: user-interface, colors, leaflet, cartography

I am working on an interactive map (Leaflet with GeoJSON layers) showing the various ethnic groups of a certain country.

**How would I go about developing a color scheme for over 26 different ethnic groups? I am working with qualitative data and want to pick a series of ‘unrelated’ colors but at the same time look really nice if all the ethnic groups layers are loaded at once on the map.**

Can one strong dark color among a group of lighter colors ‘pop’ out of the map highlighting that particular facet of data against all others?

It seems that many of the online color scheme generators only generate a max of 12 colors.

Anyone have any advice on how to develop a palette of 26 colors?

Answer (score 0):

26 colours is indeed impossible to distinguish..

Have you tried chroma.js? https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/

Here is a good example of using TopoJSON on leaflet with chroma.js:
http://blog.webkid.io/maps-with-leaflet-and-topojson/